# Using an exported symbol from a module inside linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I wrote a module which uses `EXPORT_SYMBOL(func)` to export the function func.

When modifying the kernel code,
I declared `extern void func();` at the top, and called func().

But when compiling kernel, I get *undefined reference to 'func'* error.

I guess the compiler can't find where func() is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want the kernel proper or some other kernel module use a symbol exported from your module?

Comment: See also [this documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt), might be helpful.

Comment: yes, I need the kernel proper to use the symbol exported from my module.. thanks!

Comment: Show us some code. You declare `extern void func()` at the top of what? You should use an header file, then include the header where you are implementing `func()` and where you want to use it

Comment: at the top of kernel/fork.c.. I tried what you said, I added a header file under include/linux/, the header file contains only the declaration of func(), and I made mymodule.c and kernel/fork.c include that header file.. I still get the same error.. any ideas?

Comment: this is impossible:   kernel itself, when build, is build from scratch, without assuming any dependencies on any kernel modules' existence.   so it is NOT possible for kernel itself to make any call to any kernel module.   (PLEASE note the difference between kernel code and kernel module code:   symbol dependencies is always kernel module depending on kernel, but never the other way round).